# Proteins with one SS bond?

Tags: public-databases, protein-structure

I would like to find proteins with exactly one SS bond. Is there a database where I can search this? I've tried advanced search on https://www.rcsb.org/, but no such option, at least I could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases when you cannot find answer through the web interface, you can [download all the data](http://www.wwpdb.org/download/downloads) and search it locally.

Relying on the PDB annotations of SS bonds, you could search for PDB files that have exactly one SSBOND record:

```
$ cd $PDB_DIR/structures/divided/pdb/
$ zgrep -c ^SSBOND aa/pdb*.ent.gz | grep :1$
aa/pdb2aaq.ent.gz:1
aa/pdb3aad.ent.gz:1
aa/pdb5aap.ent.gz:1
aa/pdb6aa4.ent.gz:1
aa/pdb6aa5.ent.gz:1
```

All PDB files (gzipped) take about 30GB of disk space.

The caveat is that some entries are available only in the mmCIF format. Using mmCIF would be slighty more complex: you would need to count `_struct_conn.conn_type_id` being `disulf`. And you would need to download 10GB more.

Comment: Thanks! I need just a few examples, to the 1st method is perfect!